# How to use 'starts with' or 'LIKE' clause in iot hub route query

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

**having device id "KUKU1234"**

I would like to know how to route only devices that their device id starts with 'kuku'
something like:

$connectionDeviceId LIKE 'KUKU%'

but the above throws syntax error

Comment: no, it throws Invalid built-in function 'STARTSWITH'

Comment: You can try with underscore, `STARTS_WITH($connectionDeviceId, "KUKU")`

Comment: yep, just tried it and it worked fine - thanks a lot